# android eclipse webview back navigation

Tags: android, eclipse, webview, navigation

hello i need to add back button to my app can anyone help me?

here is my code

public class Showing_now extends SherlockFragment{

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View mainView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_showing_now, container, false);
WebView webView = (WebView) mainView.findViewById(R.id.webViewsn);

webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false); 
webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);   
webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true); 
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
webView.loadUrl("http://www.mywebsite.com");
return mainView;
```

}
    public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

```
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        if (url.startsWith("http://m.youtube.com")||url.startsWith("http://www.youtube.com")) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
            return true;
        } 
        return false;
    }
```

}

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1**

Add a button to your layout `R.layout.activity_showing_now`

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/myButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="back" />
```

**Step 2**

Initialise it as normal in `onCreateView`

```
Button myButton = (Button) mainView.findViewById(R.id.myButton);
```

**Step 3**

Put an `onClickListener` on it like this:

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
        if (webView.canGoBack())
            webView.goBack();
   }
});
```